# How to Use Unicode Font with \polter command

Tags: unicode

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{holtpolt}
\begin{document}
  $\polter{abc}{def}$
\end{document}
```

Hi, I have a need to produce something thats shown in the above example however I want to use unicode text. I tried putting the unicode text in `\text{}` but it did not do the trick. Using `\text{}` worked well in mathematics. 
Thanks for your help

PS: I got this from "Comprehensive Latex Symbols list page 70" I could not come up with good title for question

Comment: I've marked your inline code with backticks `\``.

Comment: Sorry for this, \text{} works just fine, I forgot to load the Unicode package. You can delete this post if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your unicode text is just Latin (European) characters, then you need to add packages to allow both your source code to be UTF-8 encoded (`usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`) and your output (`usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`).

If what you mean by unicode text is something in a non-Latin script, then you should be using XeLaTeX.

The `\text` command is part of the `amsmath` package, so you need to load that too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{holtpolt}
\begin{document}
     $\polter{\text{éäî}}{\text{ßÍñ}}$
\end{document}
```